# Adding and removing handlers that have additional parameters?

Tags: c#

When you are adding and **removing** event handlers and you want to have additional parameters, how do you go about doing this? The below code is like something i would want but obviously does not work.

How would you go about this? - it's troublesome that i cant use delegates or lambdas as i need to also remove the handler.

```
    private static void IsDefaultChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if ((bool)args.NewValue)
        {
            Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyUp += CoreWindowOnKeyUp(dependencyObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyUp -= CoreWindowOnKeyUp(dependencyObject);
        }

    }

    private static void CoreWindowOnKeyUp(CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs args, DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        ((ICommand)dependencyObject.GetValue(Button.CommandProperty)).Execute(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is:

- Keep some collection of `DependencyObject`s that you add to/remove from in your `IsDefaultChanged` method.
- Modify your `CoreWindowOnKeyUp` handler so it only accepts the expected two parameters, and queries the collection of `DependencyObject`s itself. Bind this event once and don't unbind it.

I.e. rather than having an event with a handler for each current dependency object, you have an event with a single handler that queries a collection for current dependency objects.

```
HashTable<DependencyObject> current = new HashTable<DependencyObject>();

// Bound as before
private static void IsDefaultChanged(
    DependencyObject dependencyObject,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if ((bool)args.NewValue)
        current.Add(dependencyObject);
    else
        current.Remove(dependencyObject);
}

// Permanently bound, once.
private static void CoreWindowOnKeyUp(CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs args)
{
    foreach(var do in current)
    {
        ((ICommand)do.GetValue(Button.CommandProperty)).Execute(null);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if Richard's code doesn't unbind lambdas properly, you can keep a `Dictionary<DependencyObject, EventHandler>` so you can retrieve the *exact* lambda that was bound and unbind it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [closure](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter5/closures.aspx) to close over the dependencyObject in an anonymous delegate, not sure if the syntax is bang on but something like.

```
private static void IsDefaultChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) 
{ 
    var func = (object sender,KeyEventArgs e) =>
    {
         ((ICommand)dependencyObject
             .GetValue(Button.CommandProperty)).Execute(null); 
    };
    if ((bool)args.NewValue) 
    { 
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyUp += func; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyUp -= func; 
    } 

}
```

Comment: Will the `-=` work or will it not realise that the two lambdas are the same?

Comment: I dont think you can rely on it, so i dont think this solution is  any good.